# Databinding layout constraints

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-databinding

I have problems to add an end constraint to view

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/chatDocumentMessageContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@{chatMessage.corespondent==Corespondent.Sent? @drawable/very_rounded_corners_gray_background:@drawable/very_rounded_corners_orange_background}"
    android:maxWidth="300dp"
    android:minWidth="140dp"
    android:onClick="@{clickListener::onClick}"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_large"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@{chatMessage.corespondent==Corespondent.Sent? ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID:ConstraintSet.UNSET}">
```

I  got this error:

> [kapt] An exception occurred:
>   android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding
>   errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf' with parameter type int on
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.

Tryed adding the following adapter, but still not working:

```
 @BindingAdapter(" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf")
    fun setEndConstraint(guideline: Guideline, resource: Int) {
        val params = guideline.getLayoutParams() as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
        params.endToEnd = resource
        guideline.layoutParams = params
    }
```

Comment: try to change this one     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

Comment: @AndroidTeam i want to be conditional after chatMessage, how can i have parent if true, and none if false?

Comment: Don't do something like that. I would not answer your question becuase what you're trying to do is a bad practice. Don't do it like that.

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones why it is. I would like to remove redundant layouts.

Comment: The code is not testable. Your layout should be dumb without any logic added to them. You could easily do the same thing by putting that logic in a separate class rather than putting them in the layout themselves. Again, this is the reason why in my opinion, your question is not worth answering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I created a BindingAdapter for this kind of a situation:

```
@BindingAdapter(
    "layout_conditionalConstraint_startSide",
    "layout_conditionalConstraint_toEndId",
    "layout_conditionalConstraint_endSide",
    "layout_conditionalConstraint_condition"
)
fun setConditionalConstraint(
    view: View, startSide: Int, endId: Int, endSide: Int, condition: Boolean
) {
    val constraintLayout = (view.parent as? ConstraintLayout) ?: return
    with(ConstraintSet()) {
        clone(constraintLayout)
        if (condition) connect(view.id, startSide, endId, endSide)
        else clear(view.id, startSide)
        applyTo(constraintLayout)
    }
}
```

In your case you could use it like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/chatDocumentMessageContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@{chatMessage.corespondent == Corespondent.Sent ? @drawable/very_rounded_corners_gray_background : @drawable/very_rounded_corners_orange_background}"
    android:maxWidth="300dp"
    android:minWidth="140dp"
    android:onClick="@{clickListener::onClick}"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_large"
    app:layout_conditionalConstraint_startSide="@{ConstraintSet.END}"
    app:layout_conditionalConstraint_toEndId="@{ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID}"
    app:layout_conditionalConstraint_endSide="@{ConstraintSet.END}"
    app:layout_conditionalConstraint_condition="@{chatMessage.corespondent == Corespondent.Sent}">
```

But in most cases you should be able to get the desired layout with the features the ConstraintLayout offers, this BindingAdapter is only useful in a handful of corner cases or complex layouts.