# How can I get '@id/view_name' dynamically for databinding?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I have a TextView that I want to change the position by other view.
For example,

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    ...
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_to_follow"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

I have a button `btn_to_follow`, `btn_to_follow2`, `btn_to_follow3`.

So, I'd like to change `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` attribute dynamically with those three values.

I have a data class for state.

```
data class ButtonState(type: String){
    val followPosition = R.id.btn_to_follow
}
```

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    ...
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@{vm.followPosition}"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

I tried to change followPosition with 'R.id.xxx' values which are int values. It didn't work.

So, How can I approach what I expect??

Comment: With data binding you need to create a Binding adapter . Something [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53564844/4168607) .. If its too much and not reusable then better change it by code at runtime no need to for a Binding adapter if its not reusable.

Comment: @ADM Well, the approach seems different. I'd like to have it in the data class and how can I apply it?

Comment: What exact type `vm.followPosition` is?

Comment: Since it's resource, it's integer. The constraint attribute takes reference type and I don't know how to create the reference of each resources in the data class.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are missing is "Live" portion of it.

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@{vm.followPosition}"
```

It works, it does get the value from the `followPosition` in the `ViewModel` where `followPosition` is an `Int`.

But there isn't any implicit way how it gets updated. View was inflated and it no longer cares what is in `followPosition`.

You need `followPosition` to be `LiveData<Int>` or the parent data class to be stored in `LiveData`.

Comment: Why?? I don't think so... It doesn't need to be LiveData. LiveData is just for observing in Activity or Fragment.

Comment: No, it's not. You can set the text of some `TextView` to `LiveData<String>` and it will get updated automatically without you doing anything. That's the whole point of `DataBinding`.